# Object type boxing with a reference type variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, boxing

Boxing is when a value type is assigned to an object type. Is it the same when a reference type is assigned to an object?

When a type (which  isn't object) is assigned, what happens? Is that boxing too?

```
    int num=5;
    object obj = num;  //boxing
    //////////////////////
    MyClass my = new MyClass();
    object obj = my; //what is name this convert  (whethere is boxing?)
```

Comment: Like Henk says, all types are objects, and reference types are stored on the heap anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you mean something like

```
string s = "hello";
object x = s;        // no boxing, just implict conversion to base-type.
```

This works because `System.String`, like all other classes, derives from `System.Object`:

```
public sealed class String : Object { ... }
```

Answer (score 30):

> Boxing is when a value type is assigned to an object type.

Close. "Boxing" happens when *a value of value type* is *converted* to *a reference type*.

> Is it the same when a value of reference type is assigned to a variable of type object?

No. Boxing happens when *a value of value type* is converted to *a reference type*. Converting a value of reference type to object is not a boxing conversion, it is a reference conversion.

> When a value of reference type (which isn't object) is assigned to a variable of type object, what happens?

A value of reference type is a *reference*. When a reference is assigned to a variable of type object, a copy of the reference is made in the storage location associated with the variable.

> Is that boxing too?

No. Boxing happens when *a value of value type* is converted *to a reference type*. Converting a value of reference type to object is not a boxing conversion, it is a reference conversion.

Comment: Is it still considered a "conversion" when there is no data/type converting involved - that is, when a *conversion operator* isn't required/called during the assignment, of say `object obj = new MyClass();`?

Comment: @sαmosΛris: That is an *implicit reference conversion*.

Answer (score 2):

Boxing is creating an object reference, on the stack, that references a value of the type say for e.g. int, on the heap. But when a reference type (witch isn't object)assigned to object, it is not boxing.

Comment: Why does the reference have to be on the stack? Can't the reference be on the heap, or in a register?

Answer (score 1):

Eric's answer corresponds to the CLI (Common Language Infrastructure) standard [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), partition I (Architecture), chapter 5 (Terms and definitions), which defines boxing as: "The conversion of a value having some value type, to a newly allocated instance of the reference type System.Object.", and unboxing as: "The conversion of a value having type System.Object, whose run-time type is a value type, to a value type instance."

The box and unbox instructions of the CIL (Common Intermediate Language) behave like this, and this is also the meaning usually implied when speaking of boxing/unboxing in the context of C# or VB.NET.

However, the terms *boxing* and *unboxing* are sometimes used in a wider/pragmatic sense. For instance, the F# [box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340516.aspx) and unbox operators can do conversions of value types *and* reference types to and from System.Object:

```
> let o = box "Hello World";;
val o : obj = "Hello World"
> let s:string = unbox o;;
val s : string = "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the provided code into a working executable and disassembling it reveals an explicit box instruction for the first assignment (`obj`) that is not present for the second (`obj2`):

**Source**

```
namespace BoxingAndTypeConversion
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MyClass { }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num = 5;
            object obj = num;  //boxing
            //////////////////////
            MyClass my = new MyClass();
            object obj2 = my; //what is name this convert  (whethere is boxing?)
        }
    }
}
```

**CIL**

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       19 (0x13)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 num,
           [1] object obj,
           [2] class BoxingAndTypeConversion.Program/MyClass my,
           [3] object obj2)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloc.0
  IL_0004:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0009:  stloc.1
  IL_000a:  newobj     instance void BoxingAndTypeConversion.Program/MyClass::.ctor()
  IL_000f:  stloc.2
  IL_0010:  ldloc.2
  IL_0011:  stloc.3
  IL_0012:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```